# Linking jquery loop to react, show nothing, no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, loops

Get the same problem developing my react app. So I have import JQuery using such a command

```
npm install jquery
```

Late I download a js min file from the site,

> https://redopop.com/loupe/

You can find it at the top. It named jquery.loupe.min.js. So I copied it, and create my own js file in the src folder.

In my header i include all thees files:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import './jquery.loupe.min.js'
```

And in my function, i try to call loop:

```
  if (this.props.activeItem === "Loop") {
    $('graph').loupe();
    //window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
    //window.$('graph').loupe();
  }
```

I think that the second and third lines should work, but it gets the same result. No errors, but nothing.
My console.log of window$

```
     content.js?5f7c:406 ƒ ( selector, context ) {


    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
    return new jQuery…
```

So in my render method, I have a canvas that I want to connect with loop:

```
  <div className="canvas">
    <canvas
      id="graph"
      className="canvas-actual"
      width="800px"
      height="480px"
      ref={this.canvasRef}
      onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
      onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}
      onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
    >
    </canvas>
```

Nothing happed. No errors, or warnings.
I have no ideas that matter. Thanks.
Code (need python2)

> https://github.com/andr1312e/React-recognize

Comment: if you heed code, ask me

Comment: Dont query the dom use React API with ref. As aside note, you really shouldn't use jquery when you have React.

Comment: I do, it get me an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot define property jQuery351064704862672539812, object is not extensible

Comment: Using jQuery in react is really not recommended, if you want a loupe effect in react, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971717/magnifying-glass-that-follows-cursor-for-canvas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Andrew if you use as react.js me suggest for you library react-image-magnifiers

if use react rty use this

react-image-magnifiers:
A collection of responsive, image magnifying React components for mouse and touch.

### view in npm :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-magnifiers

### react-image-magnifiers DEMO:
https://adamrisberg.github.io/react-image-magnifiers/

### github:
https://github.com/AdamRisberg/react-image-magnifiers